# Checking values in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I'm reading in the following XML data:

```
 <Settings>
  <Display_Settings>
    <Camera>
      <Name Name="" />
      <CameraTag Tag="1" />
      <LocalPosition X="1" Y="1" Z="1" />
      <Orientation Yaw="1" Pitch="1" Roll="1" />
      <Far Far="1" />
      <Near Near="1" />
      <FOV FOV="1" />
      <AspectRatio AspectRatio="1" />
      <ScreenDistance ScreenDistance="1" />
    </Camera>
    <Camera>
      <Name Name="Camera1" />
      <CameraTag Tag="2" />
      <LocalPosition X="2" Y="2" Z="2" />
      <Orientation Yaw="2" Pitch="2" Roll="2" />
      <Far Far="2" />
      <Near Near="2" />
      <FOV FOV="2" />
      <AspectRatio AspectRatio="1" />
      <ScreenDistance ScreenDistance="2" />
    </Camera>
  </Display_Settings>
</Settings>
```

Then in my Unity program I am reading those values in and filling them out in a Dictionary as follows (only going to do a couple, not full method):

```
public struct Entry
{
    public System.Object value;
    public Type type;
}

void UpDate()
{
  var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Test.xml");
    var cameras = xdoc.Descendants("Camera");

 foreach (var camera in cameras)
 {
   // reading in values from XML
    HV_Camera _camera = new HV_Camera();
    _camera.Name = (string)camera.Element("Name").Attribute("Name");
    _camera.Tag = (string)camera.Element("CameraTag").Attribute("Tag");

    // filling out a dictionary
    _cameraEntry.type = typeof(string);
    _cameraEntry.value = (string)camera.Element("Name").Attribute("Name");
    cameraDictionary.Add("CameraName", _cameraEntry);

    _cameraEntry.type = typeof(string);
    _cameraEntry.value = (string)camera.Element("CameraTag").Attribute("Tag");
    cameraDictionary.Add("CameraTag", _cameraEntry);
      }
}
```

Now I'm trying to simply run a check to see if my dictionary has been filled out properly before I assign my stored values. But when I run my program I get the following error:

> ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the
>   dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Entry].Add
>   (System.String key, Entry value)

Can someone please tell me how I can overcome this issue? I get that it's because I have two camera frameworks in my XML but I thought I using a dictonary would allow me to store everything fine.

I've also ran a check and my XML does get read in. So it's not an issue with that.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question. I'm new to using dictionary's on this level.

*edit*

Sorry I totally forgot to add the code I have tried in reading the values.

```
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Entry> pair in settings.cameraDictionary)
        {
            if (pair.Key == "FOV")
            {
                Debug.Log("This is a test!!!");
            }
        }

        if (settings.cameraDictionary.ContainsKey("CameraName"))
        {
            Debug.Log("This is a test!!!");
        }
```

Comment: *How* did you expect the dictionary to store two values for the same key? You could use the indexer - `cameraDictionary["CameraTag"] = _cameraEntry;` but that would overwrite the previous entry, which means you're losing data. Your code looks worrying in various ways, to be honest. Why don't you just have a `Camera` type with various properties in their appropriate types?

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary is comprised of `KeyValuePair` objects, and each `Key` must be unique across the entire dictionary.

```
foreach (var camera in cameras) {
    ...
    cameraDictionary.Add("CameraName", _cameraEntry);
    ...
    cameraDictionary.Add("CameraTag", _cameraEntry);
}
```

Here you are adding two items to the dictionary, both with hard coded keys. On the second iteration of this loop, the code will attempt to add a second "CameraName" item and blow up.

Is there any particular reason you are using a `Dictionary` and not a `List<HV_Camera>`?

Comment: Probably as I've been a bit silly and been looking at this for a few days now. A list would be a hell of a lot easier. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
cameraDictionary.Add("CameraName", _cameraEntry);
```

you are adding the Property "CameraName" as the Key every time.  This is what needs to be unique.